# Getting a 404 error when running my Django server for site

Tags: python, django

I get the error:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8001/
Using the URLconf defined in recipe_organizer.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^recipes/
^media/(?P.*)$
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.

It was working not too long ago but not nothing will post.

Here is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^recipes/', include('apps.recipes.urls')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
]
```

Here is my settings(without the special key included):

```
"""
Django settings for recipe_organizer project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-------------------------------------'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.recipes',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'recipe_organizer.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'recipe_organizer.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR + '/apps/recipes/media'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    'localhost/',
)


CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And finally, here is my manage.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "recipe_organizer.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Does anyone have any ideas? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you access http://localhost:8001/admin/ ?

If yes, then the issue simply is that you haven't defined a URL entry for the root http://localhost:8001/

Something like:

```
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

should do the trick.

Don't forget to define `index` in `views.py`